# iOS WKWebView Cache size limit and location

Tags: ios, swift, caching, wkwebview

I'm using WKWebView to load couple of web games into my app.The caching is very important when it comes to the speed.

I'm using CachePolicy.returnCacheDataElseLoad, here is my call in Swift 4.

```
        let urlRequestCache = URLRequest(url: myURL!, cachePolicy: .returnCacheDataElseLoad , timeoutInterval: 100)
        webView.load(urlRequestCache)
```

Is there a cache size limit I can set, other than setting the URLCache.shared cache size, since this one seems not to have effect on WKWebView cache?

Also I've noticed that WKWebView cache is in separate folder (by data found in it), So how can I know system wont delete this cache or its files?
[image: ios App Library folder]